# EventKit private EventStore

Tags: ios, eventkit, ekeventstore

I'm new to Swift and exploring at my own pace.

I've got one simple question which might sound stupid, but here goes:

Does Apple's EventStore (from EventKit) allows you to store/read events which are specific to your app only? I'm developing a reminders functionality for my app and I don't really want these reminders to appear in iOS reminders app or in the calendar app. Would I still need to ask user permission to store dates/reminders in his/her calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I didn't find a clear answer, but it seems to me the whole point of EventKit is to access Calendar and Reminders of the iPhone and extend it with your own content.

For my scenario the best solution is to use other storage (CoreData, SQLite, Realm.io, Plist, you name it) and register for local notifications, which is more extensible and provides custom actions and custom handling of notifications you present to your users.

This [tutorial by Jameson Quave](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/local-notifications-in-ios-8-with-swift-part-2/) helped me a lot in understanding location notifications